# How to update multiple rows in postgres with golang with prepare?

Tags: postgresql, go

I want to do something like this in golang

```
    update test as t set
        column_a = c.column_a,
        column_c = c.column_c
    from (values
        ('123', 1, '---'),
        ('345', 2, '+++')  
    ) as c(column_b, column_a, column_c) 
    where c.column_b = t.column_b;
```

Where I am updating multiple rows in one round trip

Is there a way I can do this with prepare like `stmt.Exec(vals...)` where `vals = []interface{}`

Comment: Note that the linked duplicate does not use [`prepare`](https://pkg.go.dev/database/sql#DB.Prepare). If you want to use prepare to create and reuse the statement, you'll need to always pass in the same number of `vals`, because if you don't then the `Exec` will fail.